# Class to JSON VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, class, nested

So I have a class which I am serializing to Json. All goes well, until this nested class, which gives me an **System.NullReferenceException = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}**. When writing the code, intelisense recognizes  the nested class, but obviously I'm missing a declaration somewhere.

Root class:

```
    Public Class RootObject
    Private _metadata As List(Of Metadata)
    Public Property metadata() As List(Of Metadata)
    Get
        Return _metadata
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Metadata))
        _metadata = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Private _test_gl As List(Of TestGl)
    Public Property test_gl() As List(Of TestGl)
    Get
        Return _test_gl
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of TestGl))
        _test_gl = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Here is the TestGl class definition:

```
    Public Class TestGl
    Private _ref_key_3 As String
    <JsonProperty("ref-key-3")> _
    Public Property ref_key_3() As String
    Get
        Return _ref_key_3
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _ref_key_3 = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Private _currency_amount As CurrencyAmount
    <JsonProperty("currency-amount")> _
    Public Property currency_amount() As CurrencyAmount
    Get
        Return _currency_amount
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As CurrencyAmount)
        _currency_amount = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And finally the CurrencyAmount class:

```
    Public Class CurrencyAmount
    Private _currency As String
    <JsonProperty("currency")> _
    Public Property currency() As String
    Get
        Return _currency
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _currency = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Private _amount As String
    <JsonProperty("amount")> _
    Public Property amount() As String
    Get
        Return _amount
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _amount = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Here follow the code of filling up the object with data:

```
        Dim Root As RootObject
    Dim Meta_Data As New List(Of Metadata)()
    Dim Test_Gl As New List(Of TestGl)()

    Root = New RootObject
    Root.metadata = New List(Of Metadata)()
    Root.test_gl = New List(Of TestGl)
    Meta_Data = Root.metadata
    Test_Gl = Root.test_gl
```

And here I assign values to it:

```
                        Test_Gl.Add(New AccountGl)
                    Test_Gl(ItemNo).ref_key_3 = "test"
                    Test_Gl(ItemNo).currency_amount.currency = "EUR"
                    Test_Gl(ItemNo).currency_amount.amount = "100"
```

The line where currency_amount.currency gets assigned, it goes wrong and I'm looking at it for several hours already. I don't see it.
Any input would be highly appreciated.

The properties are written in full as I need to work on this project in VS2008.

Comment: This might have nothing to do with JSON. Can you run the program without the serialization part?

Comment: if Test_Gl is created from deserializing an encoded string, check that the raw JSON contains a value for currency-ammount. If not, you need to give it value before referencing it as @BlueMonkMN suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect somewhere you need to initialize `_currency_amount` to a new instance of `CurrencyAmount` I don't see `new CurrencyAmount` anywhere.

I suspect that you don't really want to allow the currency_amount property to be set, otherwise you should have set it in your sample assignment code  at the bottom. If this is the case, then you probably shouldn't even have a `Set` member defined for `TestGl` (it should be `ReadOnly`, which affects only `currency_amount` and not `_currency_amount.currency`). Instead you should create a default instance of `CurrencyAmount` and assign it to that field during the construction of `TestGl`. That could be as simple as changing your declaration of `_currency_amount` to:

```
Private _currency_amount As New CurrencyAmount
```

Alternatively, and this may be the solution you need to use with a JSON serializable object, you keep the `Set` member definition, and just add a line to your test code to initialize currency_amount before using it:

```
Test_Gl(ItemNo).currency_amount = new CurrencyAmount
```

Comment: Thank you, the last line did the trick. But why do I have to initialize the CurrencyAmount class, when it's a nested class of an already initialized root class? Should it not be initialized already at the root?

Comment: @user9671207 every declaration that refers to a class needs to be initialized to something new or something that already exists. Nested declarations are no different than root level declarations. Each one simply represents a pointer/reference to another object. The only thing that gets nested for a class (aka reference type) is the reference, not the actual instance/object to which it refers. So the root allocation only allocated space to refer to another object, not the space to actually store that object.